# UIScrollView does not scroll down

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll

I faced a strange problem, the `scrollview` does not scroll down, only scroll up. I have `scrollview` in my app, please look at my coding

```
.....

self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,427)];

[self.view addSubViews: self.scrollView];

UIView *blueView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 47, 320, 320)];

blueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

[self.scrollView addSubViews: blueView];

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(320, 640);

....
```

My problem is no matter what value I changed `contentSize`, my `ScrollView` only scroll up, not scroll down. I want user can move `blueView` to the top or bottom of iPhone screen from the original position.

do you have this problem?

Comment: if any of the answers has helped you, you should accept it according to [Stackoverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/#howtoask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Problem

It looks like your issue is with how you're orienting `blueView` within `scrollView`.  You're setting the frame of `blueView` to the `CGRect` `(0, 47, 320, 320)`.  When you set the frame like this, one of the things you're implicitly saying is:

> The top edge of `blueView` is 47 points below the top edge of `scrollView`.

That's a perfectly valid thing to say, but it's what's causing the problem you describe.  `scrollView` won't scroll down because it is designed to start, by default, with the rect `(0, 0, 320, 480)` in view.  The `contentSize` property only indicates the size of the content within the `UIScrollView`, not its positioning.  When you set it, you're basically telling `scrollView`:

> Starting from your content origin, the content is 320 points wide and 640 points tall.

Thus, `scrollView` won't scroll up because, as far as it knows, there's no content above the coordinate `(0, 0)`.

---

### The Solution

There are three steps you'll need to take to get the functionality you want.

1. Set the `contentSize` to be just big enough to allow `blueView` to scroll all the way up and down.
2. Put `blueView` in the vertical center of `scrollView`.
3. Scroll the `scrollView` so that it is initially centered on `blueView`.

- Set the `contentSize` to be just big enough to allow `blueView` to scroll all the way up and down.

We'll want to calculate the correct value of the `contentSize` property.  It is of the type `CGSize`, so we need two parts: `width` and `height`.  `width` is easy – since you don't seem to want horizontal scrolling, just make it the width of the screen, `320`.  Height is a little more tricky.  If you want `blueView` to *just* touch the top and bottom of the screen when scrolled up or down, you need to do some math.  The correct total height will be double the height of the screen, minus the height of `blueView`.  So:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480 * 2.0 - blueView.frame.size.height);
```

- Put `blueView` in the vertical center of `scrollView`.

That's easy; just set the `center` property of blueView:

```
blueView.center = CGPointMake(160, scrollView.contentSize.height / 2.0);
```

- Scroll the `scrollView` so that it is initially centered on `blueView`.

If you check the [Apple UIScrollView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW26), you'll see an instance method `- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated`.  This is exactly what you need to scroll `scrollView` programmatically.  The rect you want is the one centered on `blueView`, with the size of the iPhone screen.  So:

```
CGRect targetRect = CGRectMake(0, scrollView.contentSize.height / 2.0 - 240,
                               320, 480);
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:targetRect animated:NO];
```

Make sure you do this scrolling in `viewWillAppear`, so it's ready right when the user sees the view.

That should be it.  Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 2):

The content size of the scrollView should be the size of the view it is holding. This is how the code should be, try something like this.

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X, Y, W, H1)];
UIView * blueView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, W, H2)];
self.scrollView .contentSize = blueView.frame.size;
[self.scrollView addSubview:blueView];
[self.view addSubView: self.scrollView];
```

Thanks to Riley. Here, the H1 is the height of the UIScrollVIew and H2 is the height of the blueView and (H1 < H2).

Comment: I don't think this will achieve what rohou wants; this won't allow any scrolling of `blueView` up and down the screen.

Comment: And why is that? I use scrollview like this and works fine for me.

Comment: rohou wants a `blueView` to not fill the entire screen, but be able to be scrolled up to the top or bottom of the screen.  This code will create a `UIScrollView` that is the exact size of of `blueView`, with a `contentSize` that is also the same size as `blueView`, meaning it will not scroll.